# how to read files from a directory by using R

Tags: r, csv

I'm a new learner of R, I don't know how to read data from a directory.
The function I wrote is used to read csv files who have names like "001.csv", "002.csv"... I don't know is there any shortcut that I can avoid using the "if else" to add the "00" or "0".
Also, there is a error because I can't use data[i]( *object of type 'closure' is not subsettable*). So how do I save my data?

```
    reading <- function(directory, id = 1:500){
      for(i in length(id)){
        if(id[i]<10)
          index <- paste("00",id[i], sep = "")
        else if(id[i]<100)
          index <- paste("0",id[i], sep = "")
        else 
          index <- id[i]

        data[i] <- read.csv(paste(directory,"/",index,".csv",sep = ""))
      }
    }
```

Comment: The second "duplicate" really is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
files <- sprintf('%03d.csv', 1:500)
files1 <- paste(directory, files, sep="/")
```

Or in a single line

```
files1 <- sprintf('%s/%03d.csv', directory, 1:500) 
lapply(files1, read.csv, sep="")
```

---

If we are using as a function

```
reading <- function(directory, id = 1:500){
  files1 <- sprintf('%s/%03d.csv', directory, id)
  lapply(files1, read.csv, sep="")
 }
```

Or with `for` loop function

```
reading <- function(directory, id = 1:500){
    data <- vector('list', length(id))
    for(i in seq_along(id)){
       file <- sprintf('%s/%03d.csv', directory, id[i])
       data[[i]] <- read.csv(file, sep="")
       }
     data
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! But how I access to each file? When I type data[1],it only returns    [[1]] NULL

Comment: @Ziwei The output of the function is a `list`.  i.e. `lst <- readling(yourdirectory, id = 1:500); lst[[1]]`

Comment: Another question, how do I accsee my file like a data frame? I found I cannot do something like lst[[1]]$ID...

Comment: @Ziwei  If you want to extract a particular dataset do `d1 <- lst[[1]]` and `d1` is a `data.frame`.  So, you can access the columns by either `$` or `[`.  If you want to check through all the dataset, use `lapply` i.e. `lapply(lst, function(x) x$id)` extracts the id column.

Answer (score 0):

A more versital approach perhaps:

```
folder_files <- list.files(path = "~/Documents/My Directory/",
                        pattern = "//d+.csv", ignore.case = T, full.names = T)
#you can freely adjust pattern to any regular expression which helps in the
#long term if you have a different pattern you want to catch

readin_df <- data.frame()
for (f in folder_files) {
    df <- read.csv(f, sep = "")
    readin_df <- rbind(df, readin_df)
    }
```

Comment: I guess the OP wanted to read only certain files and not all the files based on the input in the function.

Comment: I see your point. I was trying to show how I use the list.files(pattern = "abc") to subset the directory